# Equivalent of C# code for encoding in java

Tags: java, c#, keypress, utf-16

I need to know what is the Java equivalent for the following code.
I need to pass function keys as string in Java. The following code in C# is working. I need to know how to do this in Java.

```
String escKey = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] {27});

String f1Key = escKey+ "[11~";
```

Comment: Your c# code is way more complicated than it should be. In both C# and Java, you can just do `(char)27 + "[11~"` to produce the string. You just want to produce the string, right?

Comment: This question doesn't seem in any way related to either ssh or utf-16 to me, btw.

Comment: @Sweeper in fact in C# you can specify it inside the string as hex value directly, as `"\u001B[11~"`.

Comment: @Nyerguds You could do that in Java too, but I was too lazy to do the hex conversion in my head... This just goes to show how similar the two languages are :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
Character.toString((char)27);
```

Comment: Or the OP could just do `"\u001B[11~"` or `"\033[11~"`, the first will work both in Java and in C#, and the second only in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in Java nor in C# to use such convoluted code. In both languages you can represent the escape character with the unicode escape `\u001B`, and in Java you could also use the octal escape `\033`.

So both in C# and Java you can use:

```
String f1Key = "\u001B[11~"
```

And alternatively in Java you could do:

```
String f1Key = "\033[11~"
```

But if you want the direct equivalent of your C# code in Java, it would be:

```
String escKey = new String(new byte[] { 27 }, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String f1Key = escKey + "[11~";
```

Comment: Mark Rotteveel
I am able to pass functional keys like above method for F1,F2,F3[[esckey+11~,[12~,[13~].But for F6 key this is not working.Kindly help

Comment: @Hanna I never use escape codes, but a bit of googling suggests that F1-F5 is mapped to 11-15, F6-F10 to 17-21 and F11-F12 to 23 and 24.